# mysqlslap doubles the sleep time

Tags: mysql

I'm stress testing our database with a dummy query: `Select SLEEP(2);`.
Therefore I would expect the queries to return in around 2 seconds. However mysqlslap says it would take 4 seconds to run the query.
Despite saying that, it returns the results after 2 seconds. Is that a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

The time is always doubled, so `Select SLEEP(3);` results in 6 seconds.

To reproduce:

```
mysqlslap --user=root --password=xxxxxxx --create-schema=svm_test --query="SELECT SLEEP(2);" --iterations=5  --host="127.0.0.1" --port=3307 --concurrency=1

Benchmark
Average number of seconds to run all queries: 4.009 seconds
Minimum number of seconds to run all queries: 4.000 seconds
Maximum number of seconds to run all queries: 4.016 seconds
Number of clients running queries: 1
Average number of queries per client: 1
```

I'm running MySQL 5.7.33 on Windows.

Comment: Enable general log and look what queries are sent to MySQL really.

Comment: The general log also shows correctly `Select SLEEP(2)`

Comment: I.e. your `--query="SELECT SLEEP(2);" --iterations=5` shows 5 statement copies with 2 sec. times in between? or 4 sec.?

Comment: yes, the general log is showing excactly that.

Comment: Exactly what? 2 or 4 second?

Comment: It shows 2 seconds.